# jQuery/JS: Is there a way to have only one <map> tag that will serve for multiple images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several images

```
<img usemap="#slideMap_branches"  src="branches.png" width="890" height="270" alt="Slide 4">
<img usemap="#slideMap_order" src="order.png" width="890" height="270" alt="Slide 2">
<img usemap="#slideMap_contact"  src="contact.png" width="890" height="270" alt="Slide 6">
```

and I have several `<map>` tags as well

```
<map name="slideMap_branches">
<area shape="poly" coords="500,233,378,231,378,278,-3,279,1,0,906,-1,905,281,499,277" href="javascript:alert('# branches');" target="_self" alt="slideMapPoly" />
</map>
<map name="slideMap_order">
    <area shape="poly" coords="500,233,378,231,378,278,-3,279,1,0,906,-1,905,281,499,277" href="javascript:alert('# order');" target="_self" alt="slideMapPoly" />
</map>
<map name="slideMap_contact">
    <area shape="poly" coords="500,233,378,231,378,278,-3,279,1,0,906,-1,905,281,499,277" href="javascript:alert('# contact');" target="_self" alt="slideMapPoly" />
</map>
```

Basically, all map areas have the same coordinates, they are just of different HREF attributes to point to different links, not the same one.

I wonder if there can be a javascript/jquery way to have only one `<map>` and `<area>` tag and when user clicks on the image browser recognizes which image was clicked and what to do.

I tried several methods but could never get image ID/name/src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to have the same clickable area on 3 different images, and have each image link to something different?

See what I've done below.  It gets the job done.  Maybe there is a better way?
Notice the images have a click event, and when the map area is clicked a flag is set to identify that a correct part of the image was clicked.  Where I have alert("clicked on " + T.src), you would decide what to do based on what image was clicked (either based on the src, or maybe a custom attribute).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var linkout = false;

            function LinkOut() {
                linkout = true;
            }

            function imgClick(T) {
                if (linkout) {
                    alert("clicked on " + T.src);

                }
                linkout = false;
            }
        </script>

        <map name="slideMap">
            <area shape="poly" coords="500,233,378,231,378,278,-3,279,1,0,906,-1,905,281,499,277" href="javascript:LinkOut();" target="_self" alt="slideMapPoly" />
        </map>
        <img usemap="#slideMap"  src="branches.png" width="890" height="270" alt="Slide 4" onclick="imgClick(this);">
        <img usemap="#slideMap" src="order.png" width="890" height="270" alt="Slide 2" onclick="imgClick(this);">
        <img usemap="#slideMap"  src="contact.png" width="890" height="270" alt="Slide 6" onclick="imgClick(this);">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh, I completely follow your logic and it's great, however I cannot ever initiate an onclick="" on <img>... If I remove usemap="#slideMap" then onclick="" works, otherwise it does not.. Maybe I have some other issue, I'll work on it more, will see if I can find a way around. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I was trying this using IE9 and the click event fires on both the <area> and <img>.  In chrome I see that only one of the events is firing.

Comment: I'm also using IE9, could not find a way around but I see a logic, but cannot make it work on my machine, but thanks. Still I accept your answer.